# fullCalendar - any way to add an image to an event based on some criteria?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have event populating my full calendar and I'd like to add an icon to some of the events that meet a certain criteria. For example, my calendar events are representations of work orders that will be added to routes. So if a work order is in a route, I'd like the event that represents that work order to have an icon in the title that signifies that it is part of a route.

I could just change the event's color, but I'd like more than just color. Am I asking too much? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
eventRender: function(event, element, calEvent) {
        element.find(".fc-event-title").after($("<span class=\"fc-event-icons\"></span>").html("<img src=\"images/on1.jpg\" />"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. In `eventRender` you can look for and manipulate `.fc-event-title` (mind that some "short" events may not have this markup), or just add a class with an image background, or add a dingbat (bullet here), like:
`.fcimg .fc-event-title:before {content: "\025cf\00020";}`

Answer (score 0):

You may also do a little modification in the plugin that is in DayEventRenderer.js file goto "`daySegHTML`" function and in that right after the condition `if (!event.allDay && seg.isStart)` (that is the start of the making of event div itslef) insert the following statement:

```
if (event.imgSource != '')
            html += "<div><img src='" + event.imgSource + "' style='display:inline;width:2.0em;height:2.0em;margin-bottom:0.5em'></div>";
```

Note that `event.imgSource` is not the builtin event property but you have to provide it while providing the event data.

So if you dont provide `event.imgSource` nothing will get included and if you provide the image source it will automatically add it.

Hope this will resolve the issue :)